# Twitter API accept follow request

Tags: javascript, php, api, twitter

Is there a way to accept a follow request with the twitter API when the twitter account is a protected account?
I looked for the resource URL but I didn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question - I don't know why you're being downvoted.

Sadly, the answer is "no".  [There is no API for accepting follower requests](https://twittercommunity.com/t/auto-accept-twitter-followers-requests/46049/2).

You can see who has made requests to follow you using [friendships/incoming](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-friendships-incoming).